# How to put name an array of JSON objects using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm creating a JSON file with GSON, but the arrays doesn't have names.

My result:

```
[
      {
      "name": Jonh,
      "date": "Feb 16, 2066",
      "hour": "10:15:00 PM"
   },
      {
      "name": Maria,
      "date": "Feb 16, 2066",
      "hour": "10:15:00 PM"
   }
]
```

What I need:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user": [
      {
        "name": John,
        "date": "Feb 16, 2066",
        "hour": "10:15:00 PM"
      },
      {
        "name": Maria,
        "date": "Feb 16, 2066",
        "hour": "10:15:00 PM"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Someone knows how can I put name an arrays?

--EDIT

I'm using this code for generate my JSON file.

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("user/list")
    public String getListUsers() throws Exception {

        List<Object> list;

        UserDAOImpl daoUser = new UserDAOImpl();
        list = daoUser.listAllUsers();

        Gson g = new Gson();
        return g.toJson(list);

    }
```

Comment: what is your input and relevant source code?

Comment: This is a json array. What clase are those ojects? You need a wrapping class that contamina the list to generarte it as want it.

Comment: Objects are from User class

Comment: You already seem to know how to create a JSON object (`{}`) using a Java class, and a JSON array (`[]`) using a `List`, so what's the difficulty in creating more Java objects to create more JSON objects? I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a new Object inside which you'll have to put your list and convert that object to JSON.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(list).getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject userJsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("user", jsonArray);
JsonObject usersJsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("users", usersJsonObject);
```

I haven't tried the code. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> user = new TreeMap<>();
user.put("user", list);
Map<String, Map<String, List<Object>>> users = new TreeMap<>();
users.put("users", user);
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(users);
```